# Full subcategory of objects equals to the sum of all their noetherian subobjects

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a Grothendieck category, consider the full subcategory $N(\mathcal{C})$ consisting of the objects of $\mathcal{C}$ which are the sum of their noetherian subobjects. Is $N(\mathcal{C})$ closed under quotient objects and arbitrary direct sums?

Idea for quotient objects: let $M \in N(\mathcal{C})$ and let $L$ be a quotient object of $M$. Let $\{L_\lambda\}$ be the family of all noetherian subobjects of $L$. Then, if $ \sum_{\lambda} L_\lambda \neq L $, then there is a subobject $A$ of $L$ such that: $$ \sum_{\lambda} L_\lambda \subset A \subset L, $$ if I prove that $A$ is noetherian then I have the claim. Can be the right way?